# XGBoost with GPU support on Google Colab

Tags: gpu, xgboost, google-colaboratory

Is there a way to import the XGBoost with GPU support on Google Collab? At last, I tried yesterday and the loaded XGBoost does not have the GPU support.

You could reach the notebook from this link: https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1YxCw7eVHZDrbVBFqSN0-t1mZ-fBJJI7h

And the error is:

> XGBoostError: b'[19:15:28] src/learner.cc:151: XGBoost version not
> compiled with GPU support.\n\nStack trace returned 10 entries:\n[bt]
> (0)
> /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/xgboost/./lib/libxgboost.so(_ZN4dmlc15LogMessageFatalD1Ev+0x3c)
> [0x7eff3d42f8ac]\n[bt] (1)
> /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/xgboost/./lib/libxgboost.so(_ZN7xgboost11LearnerImpl17ConfigureUpdatersEv+0x2a1)
> [0x7eff3d439561]\n[bt] (2)
> /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/xgboost/./lib/libxgboost.so(_ZN7xgboost11LearnerImpl9ConfigureERKSt6vectorISt4pairINSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEES8_ESaIS9_EE+0x35b)
> [0x7eff3d43ba2b]\n[bt] (3)
> /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/xgboost/./lib/libxgboost.so(XGBoosterUpdateOneIter+0x47)
> [0x7eff3d59cdc7]\n[bt] (4)
> /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libffi.so.6(ffi_call_unix64+0x4c)
> [0x7eff5dd19e18]\n[bt] (5)
> /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libffi.so.6(ffi_call+0x32a)
> [0x7eff5dd1987a]\n[bt] (6)
> /usr/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload/_ctypes.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so(_ctypes_callproc+0x4cd)
> [0x7eff5df2d96d]\n[bt] (7)
> /usr/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload/_ctypes.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so(+0x8727)
> [0x7eff5df24727]\n[bt] (8)
> /usr/bin/python3(_PyObject_FastCallDict+0xa3) [0x459893]\n[bt] (9)
> /usr/bin/python3() [0x54f117]\n'

Comment: What did you try, and what error did you encounter? (A shared notebook would be helpful.)

Answer (score 1):

Download the Linux version from [here](https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/xgboost-wheels/list.html), and then

```
!pip uninstall xgboost
!pip install xgboost-0.81-py2.py3-none-manylinux1_x86_64.whl
```

...is working for me.